# Placing 'supposedly' in a sentence

Tags: adverb-placement

> He left the party because he was supposedly ill, but really he didn't want to be there.
>
> He left the party because supposedly he was ill, but really he didn't want to be there.
>
> He left the party supposedly because he was ill, but really he didn't want to be there.

*Supposedly* could be placed in one of three or four positions in the first part of the sentence, so I am not sure where best to place it.

Comment: The third one is slightly accusatory as if you don't believe him. The second one, while not incorrect, is the most awkward because it interrupts your flow a little bit. The first one is the most "objective," that is, it imparts no judgment and is (almost) a mere statement of fact. By the way, the second one would need commas around "supposedly."

Answer (score 1):

Use:

> He left the party because he was **supposedly ill**, but really he didn't want to be there.

[*supposed*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/supposed) as used here means:

> adjective
>   1. (prenominal)
>   presumed to be true without certain knowledge

In your example, the presumed information is the *illness*. While you could move *supposedly* around, it would be more understandable (esp. in speech) to put it directly before what it is modifying.